# Photoshop: Rounding Corners/Edges on Text/Font

Tags: adobe-photoshop, fonts, text, photoshop-effects

I would like to have this:
[image]

Turn into this:
[image]

I used the "stroke" effect set to "outside" with 169px to get it nice and thick.
However, the effect does not produce completely smooth corners. 
See here:
[image]

What is the best way to round font/text edges and get a perfect smooth result? 
I am open to any suggestions, it does not have to be the "stroke" method.

Edit: Ok not all suggestions:I do not want to use "Quick Mask Mode/Gaussian Blur"
http://www.itechies.net/tutorials/psexample/index-pid-round-text.htm

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are using blending options for applying stroke to get a round corner

You could use this method (works with Photoshop CS6 or Above) for your required result (for a smooth rounded corner)

1. After creating your text Right click on the layer and select Convert to shape.
2. Select your shape with the help of `Direst selection tool` and apply a stroke with the required thickness.
3. In `Stroke Option` select `Align:` to centre or outside and `Corners:` to Smooth.

[image]

Here's is my result

[image]

Comment: Oh that looks great!  Yes I was using Blending Options!  Trying your suggestion now. Thank you!

Comment: I am using CS5, how do I get Stroke Options after I select with the "Direct Selection Tool"?

Comment: This method requires cs6. Honestly there isn't a super good method for older versions. If you have it, you should do it in Illustrator.

Comment: Ah!  Thank you, that explains why I could not find it anywhere. I have CS6 on a different computer, I will do it there. Thank you.

Comment: It's right next to ` Stroke: `. option. I have installed Adobe Photoshop CS6 & cc 2014 in my machine and I am sure it should be present in CS5 Version too.
I have edited my answer with a new snapshot (I hope this will help you)

Comment: @Rishab.Ag I edited to my answer with a photo to show you where I get stuck. Thank you!

Comment: @Joonas I have Illustrator CS5. How would I do it there?

Comment: I got it in CS6! So can you please edit your answer to state that photoshop needs to be CS6 or newer? Thanks!

Comment: Great @IHeartBeats I strongly recommend you to update your software to its latest version. There is a lot more flexibility in them